# Extract active gateway into variable using batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am trying to get the active gateway IP into a variable using a windows batch script.  Can only use native tools.

Therefore I am using the command 'route'.  An example print out is as follows:

`route print -4 0.*`

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  4...2e 33 7a f5 ff e9 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  3...8c ae 4c ee 07 84 ......ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter #2
 14...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
  5...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
 11...00 ff a7 b1 54 e7 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 12...2c 33 7a f5 ff e9 ......Dell Wireless 1560 802.11ac
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  2...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.55.254    192.168.55.53     10
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.111.111       1
===========================================================================
```

As you can see I have an Active route and Persistent route. Both of which have a Gateway address.

I only want the Active Gateway IP as a variable.

So far I have created this command:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.* ^| find "0."') do set "_active_gateway_address=%%a"
```

Unfortunately this results in the persistent gateway (192.168.111.111) being captured as a variable as it's the last entry found.

How can I capture only the active gateway (192.168.55.254) or make 'find' stop when it finds the first match?

Many thanks

Comment: Add a `& goto break` command after the `set` and put the label `:break` below the `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - Read only the first value using the variable as a flag

```dos
set "_active_gateway_address="
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('
    route -4 print 0.* ^| find "0."
') do if not defined _active_gateway_address set "_active_gateway_address=%%a"
```

or with the `goto` command

```dos
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('
    route -4 print 0.* ^| find "0."
') do set "_active_gateway_address=%%a" & goto :done
:done
```

Option 2 - Check the fifth token presence

```dos
for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in ('
    route -4 print 0.* ^| find "0."
') do if not "%%b"=="" set "_active_gateway_address=%%a"
```